# Reseting classloader of a maven plugin

Tags: java, classloader, maven-plugin

I built a maven plugin and I modify its classloader in order to be able to take resources and create objects of classes of the module I am executing the plugin on. So everything works fine when I execute the plugin on one module, but the problems come when I execute it on several child modules when I run the build of the root project. So the first execution is fine, but when it proceeds to the second module it seems to have kept the ClassLoader modifications of the first execution and as I have 2 files with the same name in the 2 modules and I took them as a resource from the ClassLoader it always loads the first file(as it is added first). This makes me think that the execution of the plugin is in one process with one ClassLoader. So what I thought is that I have to somehow reset the ClassLoader on every execution. So what I tried is the following:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new URLClassLoader(new URL[0], null));
```

This is because I saw that it should use a bootstrapped ClassLoader when you set it to null. But unfortunately it didn't work. So has anybody any idea how to reset the ClassLoader?

Comment: new URL[0],what possible help will you get from an array of size 0?

Comment: There's no help, but as I could see that is the array which contains the libs I want to add to the classpath. As I don't want to add anything I make it empty, because with null is throwing NPE.